# Why is Laravel PHPUnit in-memory test seeding my main db?

Tags: sqlite, laravel-4, phpunit, in-memory

**[UPDATE] Testing seems to work find in-memory if i used query builder (i.e. DB::table()), but uses main table when using Eloquent. Still no hint.**

I have followed these 2 tutorials to get in-memory testing to work:

[testing-like-a-boss-in-laravel-models](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/testing-like-a-boss-in-laravel-models--net-30087)

[laravel-setting-up-an-in-memory-test-database](http://ryanstelmat.com/laravel-setting-up-an-in-memory-test-database/)

I first tried with migrating/seeding a table that doesn't exist in my main mysql database. Everything was fine, the table was not created in mysql and test assertion was successful.

Then I tried migrating/seeding/in-memory testing with a real table, found that it was seeded in my main mysql db.

Newly trying in-memory testing. Need help with this: 
1. No idea why my main db is being touched.
2. How to verify in-memory db is populated? Any way to browse through it?

Main steps followed:

in app/config/testing/database.php

```
'default' => 'testing',

'testing' => array(
            'driver'   => 'sqlite',
            'database' => ':memory:',
            'prefix'   => '',
        )
```

in phpunit.xml, added this:

```
<php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="testing"/>
    </php>
```

in TestCase class:

```
public function createApplication()
    {
        $unitTesting = true;
        $testEnvironment = 'testing';
        return require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/start.php';
    }
```

in my test class:

```
public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        Artisan::call('migrate');
        Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--class' => 'DatabaseSeeder', '--database' => 'testing']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`function setUp()` is runned before each test. If you check your `setUp` you can see a migrate and a seed. If you remove `Artisan::call('db:seed)` in your setUp, your database will be without seed data on every test of your class.

Then, this is your new code:

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    Artisan::call('migrate');
    // Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--class' => 'DatabaseSeeder', '--database' => 'testing']);
}
```

Comment: I think this does not answer the question. @aiiwa need to run the test case with data seeded but he doesn't want the data to be saved into main database once the test case is run.